# What are the significant differences between Tamron and Sigma 17-50mm f/2.8 lenses?

Tags: sigma, tamron, lens-recommendation

I am so close to buying one of these two lenses, both with image stabilization for my Nikon D7100.

Can anyone help me decide by giving me any important differences or sharing any experience?

Comment: I got the Tamron SP AF 17-50mm f/2.8 VC, its a good lens but there is one deal breaker for and if I knew this I would not buy! The issue is that the image stabilization needs a split of a second to work. When pressing the camera button halfway to shoot, with this lens, you can hear the image stabilization on the lens "initiating" for a split of a second. And then, and only then you should full press the camera button to shoot. Where's the problem? If you don't wait for the img stabilizer to finish and you shoot it comes out blurry because at the time of initiation the camera is shaking a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing first person, but Photozone.de's tests and reviews are well regarded. Here's the relevant links:

http://www.photozone.de/nikon--nikkor-aps-c-lens-tests/642-tamron175028vcdx
http://www.photozone.de/nikon--nikkor-aps-c-lens-tests/838-sigma175028os

To summarize:
Build quality of both is good but not fantastic
Neither is a great lens to manual focus
Both have poor distortion at 17mm that goes away as focal length increases
Resolution is pretty close at wider focal lengths, but at 50mm Sigma is clearly better, especially wide open.

If I didn't have Canon's 17-55/2.8 I would choose the Sigma.

Comment: Can you summarize the links and include the important points? If the linked to website is unavailable we still want to have relevant content here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the Tamron SP AF 17-50mm f/2.8 XR Di II LD IF to the Sigma 17-50mm f/2.8 EX DC OS HSM, the image quality comparison is [available here](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=400&Camera=474&Sample=0&FLI=0&API=0&LensComp=729&CameraComp=0&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0).

Roll over the images to see the difference, check for acuteness (perceived sharpness), chromatic aberration, vignetting.

I tried to summarize my opinion, but you should check all the combination of focal length and aperture you are interested in.

Now, if you want to compare the Tamron SP AF 17-50mm f/2.8 XR Di II **VC** LD IF to the same Sigma, the comparison is available [on this link](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=679&Camera=474&Sample=0&FLI=0&API=0&LensComp=729&CameraComp=474&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0).

This "VC" lens seems to be pretty different if you compare it with the non-VC lens.